# Angular 1.5.x Routing Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I've looked at dozens of questions here about Angular routing but haven't been able to get this working. I apologize if I overlooked anything. I've been trying to use the Angularjs official tutorial and seed repository to get a simple app off the ground. This code is hosted on a web server but for this purpose, I copied my code over to Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lKyTcXafz2mZIwucxnJ). The code is also below - thank you for any insight you might provide.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller='homeCtrl'>
    <h2>{{ location }}</h2>
    <p>This is the home page content.</p>
    <a href='#faq'>FAQ</a>
</div>
```

faq.html

```
<div ng-controller='faqCtrl'>
    <h2>This is the FAQ.</h2>
    <p>{{ question }}</p>
</div>
```

Script1

```
angular.module('testApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'home',
    'faq'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/');
}]);
```

Script2

```
angular.module('home', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'homeCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('homeCtrl', [function ($scope) {
    $scope.location = 'USA';
}]);
```

Script3

```
angular.module('faq', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/faq', {
        templateUrl : 'faq.html',
        controller : 'faqCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('faqCtrl', [function ($scope) {
    $scope.question = 'Who am I?';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typos/omissions in your app:

In index.html, you are missing the app name in `ng-app`:

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
```

In your "home" and "faq" controllers, you need to use the [correct syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation) for the injections:

Use:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

Instead of:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', [function ($scope) {
```

Finally, in home.html and faq.html, do not use `ng-controller` at all. In your route definitions, you are specifying the controller to use for each route. Specifying it again inside the template will result in a second controller being instantiated.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BzE4fiTb1BA3nzbHAHxq?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks - I see the changes you made did fix the code in the Plunker link. But when I edited the code on my web server - specifically changing `<html ng-app>` to `<html ng-app="testApp">`, it did the opposite, the entire page went blank - even the header snippet was gone. Changing it back to just `<html ng-app>` brings the header back. Any ideas?

Comment: The name you pass to `ng-app` should match the name of your app's main module. In the code of above that is "ng-app" (from Script1). In your real app, maybe you are using a different name?

Comment: Yeah the name matches the module's name. I don't see why the behavior would be any different on the real app than Plunker.

Comment: I stepped away from the problem for a few minutes after making the edits you suggested and it ended up working. Thank you very much, I've been driving myself crazy. I was looking at an app written with Angular 1.2.x as a guide and I think the big thing I was missing was after 1.2.x dependency injections need to be explicit instead of implicit.